# Bulk reset passwords in Active Directory by mask

Tags: active-directory

I have thousands of users in a specific OU that I want to reset their password. It can be the same password, but not ALL of the users in that specific OU. I need to be able to do it for users that have usernames that start with a certain pattern.

Example, I have users that start with TPA*, or IDH*, but NOT AAA*.

I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/207115/how-do-i-bulk-reset-passwords-for-all-users-in-an-ou#log-in) that does the reset for ALL users, I was wondering if the dsquery could be tweaked to add in a mask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a little more research...

```
dsquery user "ou={userdirectorychild},ou={userdirectory},dc={mydc},dc={mydc},dc={mydc}" -name tp* | dsmod user -pwd {newpassword}
```